# Jquery - dynamically change a row height of a table.

Tags: jquery, height, row, datatables

I am using a Jquery's datatable. I have a table with id = "affectedRegion". It has a column with a radio button inside it. In part, some of the styling around this radio button cell gives each row it's height.

In a special case, I have to hide the radio button column by doing something like this

```
affectedRegion.fnSetColumnVis(0, false);
```

However, when I do this, the rows become much shorter than what I want. Since this code is shared at many other places, I would like to know if there is a way in Jquery that I can change the row height dynamically to maintain the same look and feel.

I tried the below and it doesn't work.

```
$("#affectedRegion").css('height', '25px');
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: what is #affectedRegion? Is it a table row?  Can you show some more of your code, or set up http://jsfiddle.net/ to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Nope, affected region is the table, not the table row. I don't have the id of the table rows. Thanks for trying though. You can look at the jsFiddle below by David (http://jsfiddle.net/wDTYJ/), except that the <tr> doesn't have an id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I set up a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wDTYJ/) to demo setting the row height of a table row, and it seems to work fine.  I'm using Chrome, if that helps.

I'm changing the height of the `<tr>` tag, if that helps.

If you have other questions, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Good luck. Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**  Updated my [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/wDTYJ/1/).  If you have access to the index of the row to be resized, you can use jQuery's `eq` function to only affect that table row in your table.  I'm not sure if this helps or not, but this allows you to get away from having an id or some sort of marker class assigned to each row.

> HTML

```
<table id='affectedRegions'>
    <tr id='affectedRegion'>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>There</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='affectedRegion2'>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>There</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> jQuery

```
//change the height of the 2nd table row within #affectedRegions table
// eq() is zero-based.
$('#affectedRegions tr').eq(1).css('height', '200px');
```

Comment: Thanks David. However, your example assumes that the I have an id for the <tr> and also that there is only 1 or may be few rows that are to be assigned a particular height. However, the table data is dynamically generated and I don't have control over the number of rows.

Comment: I updated my answer (and my fiddle) to use jQuery's `eq` function to access table rows by index instead of by ID.

Comment: Thanks David. That works for me. Also, another way I found was to give the <tr> a class and then use a class selector, so my solution looks like this.
    $('.tableRowClass').css('height','25px');